# prove that the number of nodes in a binary tree is one less than the number of leaves

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

"A full node in a binary tree is a node with two children. Prove that the number of full nodes in a (non-empty)
binary tree is one less than the number of leaves"

I ran into this problem which i have no idea what it's asking me because we haven't done these sort of problems in lectures at all. What is it asking me to do and how do "prove" it?

Thank you

edit: Here is what I've done. I am not too sure if this is correct but the question says I try and explain it using English instead of using maths

"Considering the base case where there is a single node, this implies that the tree has a single leaf and has no nodes with two children. This is one less than the number of leaves. If a node is added to a node with 0 children, the single node with two children and the number of leaves do not vary. If a node is added to a node with a child, the number of nodes with two children and the number of leaves is increased by 1. To conclude, adding a node to an existing node is an impossible feat. The difference between the nodes in a binary tree will always be one less than the number of leaves because attempting to add a node to the tree does not change or either increases the number of tree and leaves by 1."

Comment: There is a lot of reading about binary trees. Draw minimal binary tree on a paper and check conditions visually. Try to add nodes and check further.

Comment: This is a math problem. "How to construct a proof in mathematics" is a very fundamental question, not really suitable for this site.

Comment: 1. not really a stack overflow question
2. what did you till now? I would assume a brief google search will get you the right answer

Comment: Well, I mulled over the question and still got nothing on how to prove it. I googled it and what I found didn't really help me understand it until I asked here.

Answer (score 3):

What your course calls "binary trees" are known in math as rooted binary trees. Only rooted trees have the concept of children nodes, in a non-rooted tree there's no parent-child hierarchy, all nodes are equal. The statement is only true in general with respect to non-empty rooted trees.

Here's a detailed proof by induction.

1. Induction base. The statement is obviously true for a one-node tree: it has one leaf (the root) and no full nodes.
2. Induction step. Suppose the statement is true for all rooted binary trees with *N* nodes, for some positive integer *N*. Given a tree *T* with *N+1* nodes, select a leaf *L* and remove it. The result is a tree *T'* with *N* nodes, for which the statement is true. Say the parent of *L* is *L'*. There are two cases:

   - *L'* is a leaf in *T'*. Then *T* has the same number of leaves as *T'* (because one leaf, *L*, is added and one node, *L'*, loses its leaf status). The number of full nodes is the same in *T* and in *T'* (because the same nodes are full).
   - *L'* has exactly one child in *T'*. Then *T* has one more leaf than *T'* (because *L* is a new leaf) and one more full nodes than *T'* (because *L'* is a new full node).

   In either of these cases, the difference between the number of leaves and the number of full nodes doesn't change. It follows that the statement is true for all rooted binary trees with *N+1* nodes.

By the principle of induction, the statement is true for all positive integers *N*.

A much shorter (but still perfectly acceptable) version of this proof would read as follows:

- Collapse one leaf with its parent node. The difference between the number of leaves and the number of full nodes doesn't change then.

This answer doesn't attempt to explain what a [mathematical proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof) is, or provide general methods of constructing proofs.

Answer (score 0):

```
fn = no. of full nodes 
l = no. of leaves
n = no. of nodes
h = height of tree
```

For a full tree:

```
h = log (n+1)
```

And,

No. of nodes = 2 * full nodes + the root

That is:

```
2 * fn +1 = n
```

Also,

```
l = 2^(h-1)
```

since nodes in every row besides root is twice the number compared to the previous row.

So,

```
l= 2^ (log (n+1) -1) = (n+1)/2
```

Or,

```
n = 2 * l -1
```

From previous deductions:

```
2 * fn + 1 = 2 * l - 1
```

Or,

```
fn + 1 = l
```

Comment: >h = log (n+1)


Why do you logaithms? I don't really understand

Comment: The question asks about binary trees in general, not just full binary trees.

Comment: @n.m. it talks about non-empty binary tree. The question asked would stand true only for full binary trees.

Comment: @Paul Zhu you might have to prove it separately. Here's a proof by induction http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/JamesStewart/378notes/09treeHeight/

Comment: No, it is true for all (rooted) non-empty binary trees.

Comment: @n.m. non-empty implies full binary tree

Comment: Specifically, it works for any binary tree  because you can simply collapse any one-child node without changing the number of full nodes or leaves. After you remove all the one-child nodes, you have a full tree.

Comment: Um, no. What about this tree: `root ---> node ---> node ---> node ---> leaf`?

Comment: @n.m. There can be specific cases where this would hold true, but as a theorem it would hold true only for full binary tree and not for every binary tree.

Comment: "non-empty implies full binary tree" I just gave you an example of non-empty non-full tree. "and not for every binary tree" Give a counterexample then.

Comment: @n.m. Just checked again and your understanding is correct